# Symfony 3 FormType use translation for attr

Tags: php, forms, validation, translation, symfony

I'm currently working on a FormType for a person. I want a custom validity message, so I use the `oninvalid` and `onchange` attributes. However, the translations used within those attributes won't work. I only get a custom validity message saying "person.label.firstname".

The translations for the label and placeholder do work. So why doesn't it work with the onchange and oninvalid? (Yes, the translations do exist)

```
$builder->add("firstname", TextType::class, array(
                "label" => "person.label.firstname",
                "attr" => array("placeholder" => "person.label.firstname",
                    "pattern" => "^[a-zA-Z \-]+",
                    "oninvalid" =>  'setCustomValidity("person.validity.firstname")')
            ))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation for `placeholder` works, because `trans` filter is applied in the default template for rendering form widgets, as you can see here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L333

But even if `trans` filter was applied to all attributes, it probably still wouldn't behave as expected, because the value of `oninvalid` is `setCustomValidity("person.validity.firstname")`, and I'm guessing you want to have only `person.validity.firstname` translated.

To solve your problem, inject `translator` service into your form type and set attributes with explicitly translated values:

```
    $builder->add("firstname", TextType::class, array(
            "label" => "person.label.firstname",
            "attr" => array("placeholder" => "person.label.firstname",
                "pattern" => "^[a-zA-Z \-]+",
                "oninvalid" => 'setCustomValidity("' . $this->translator->trans('person.validity.firstname') . '")'
        ))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. But the translator is an undefined method inside that FormType. So for example, how do I inject the validators yaml translation file?

Comment: To inject a service into your form, you must register it as a service. Here's the documentation article about how to do it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-field-service